# How does cloudformation protect Elasticsearch cluster data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cloudformation

I am using CloudFormation to deploy an Elasticsearch cluster to AWS managed Elasticsearch service. The CloudFormation template includes all resources like `domain`, `iam role`, `policy`.

If I update the policy or role for the ES domain, does CloudFormation turn down the cluster and redeploy a new one?

I'd like to know what change will cause a redeploy because it is very risky which may lead to lose data. Changes like `update size`, `shard number`, `policy`, `role` etc. But I can't find anything in the doc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the particular property you want to modify in [AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticsearch-domain.html#cfn-elasticsearch-domain-accesspolicies).

Changing a given property can [result in either](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html#update-no-interrupt):

- Update with No Interruption
- Updates with Some Interruption
- **Replacement**

For instance:

- `AccessPolicies`: Update requires: No interruption
- `DomainName`: Update requires: **Replacement**

`Replacement` will lead to tearing down your domain, and **loosing your data**. However, there are **few things** you can do to check what is replaced and how to protect from it:

- [UpdateReplacePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatereplacepolicy.html) - "Use the UpdateReplacePolicy attribute to retain or (in some cases) backup the existing physical instance of a resource when it is replaced during a stack update operation."
- [stack policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/protect-stack-resources.html#stack-policy-reference) - enables you to deny any updates that would result in deletion or replacement of a resource.
- [change sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-changesets.html) - before any update, execute a change set to check if the update you want to perform can result in replacements.
- [manual backups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html) before any updated, make a backup of your ES domain to avoid loosing your data.